# POJO Annotations are not being reflected with Kundera

Tags: java, annotations, cassandra, spring-batch

I am writing one simple Spring Batch Application which reads data from a file and write it into  Cassandra DB.

If I run the Cassandra CRUD operations in a simple java project with one single below dependency, I was able to run it properly. And I could execute CRUD operations successfully.

Dependency :
        
            com.impetus.client
            kundera-cassandra
            2.5

Now here comes the problem!

I am integrating the same code with Spring Batch application. I am ending up with below exception:

```
10:22:19,816 DEBUG ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1 dao.JdbcStepExecutionDao:203 - Truncating long message before update of StepExecution, original message is: org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:196)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.access$100(FlowJob.java:43)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob$JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:266)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
; com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: Entitymatadata should not be null
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:174)
    at org.springframework.batch.admin.zipfeed.ZipLocationFeedWriter.write(ZipLocationFeedWriter.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Now I compared the both application debugging further. It looks like the below annotation are not getting reflected while running Spring Batch Application. FYI, I have provided the bean which I am using to do CRUD operations. The same bean is working for standalone application (jUnit).

Please let me know how to get this working. Looks like the annotations are not getting reflected while running batch application. (FYI, I have taken the screen shot too for easy understanding)

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "ZipLookUp", schema = "ZipDB@cassandra_pu")
   public class ZipLocationBean {

          @Id
          @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE")
          private String zipcode;
          @Column(name = "CITY")
          private String city;
          @Column(name = "STATE")
          private String state;
          @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
          private String country;
          @Column(name = "LATITUDE")
          private double latitude;
          @Column(name = "LONGITUDE")
          private double longitude;
          // Getters and setters;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify if you have:

`<bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />`

is present in spring configuration.

-Vivek

Comment: also You need to add given below dependency for spring-orm: 
  ``<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>``

Comment: After moving the Tomcate instalation directory to a folder without any spaces, this problem got resolved. Thanks Vivek for your suggestion offline.